# passing parameters to crm 2011 url

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a silverlight application installed in my crm 2011, I need to get the account Id in my application so I need to pass a value of a guid account to the url.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any details of what you want to do, you'd be better off looking at some examples.

Google, as always, is your friend:

http://blog.webmastersam.net/post/Easily-pass-parameters-to-Silverlight.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328358.aspx